# Angular - Can i access a controller's variable in a module?

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app, if a user is logged in I do not want them to be able to got the `login` page.

In my main controller I have a method `isAuthed()` that returns a boolean informing me of this status. However how do i access it in my `ngRoute` module. I'm using the code below:

```
.when("/login",
            {
              templateUrl: "views/login.html",
              controller: 'Main',
              controllerAs: 'main',
              resolve:{
                "check":function($location){
                    if($scope.main.isAuthed()){
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                }
            }
            }
)
```

SOLUTION:

I needed to add it in as a service:

```
.when("/login",
            {
              templateUrl: "views/login.html",
              controller: 'Main',
              controllerAs: 'main',
              resolve:{
                "check":function($location, authService){
                    if(authService.isAuthed()){
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                }
            }
            }
)
```

Comment: I think you're better off using a service which can be injected into your resolve function.

Comment: There is no `$scope` in the `config` and controller hasn't even been activated before resolve and you have no access to controllers there either. As mentioned this needs to be a service method or function defined within `config`

Comment: So do i pass the service next to $location?
i.e. `"check":function($location, authService){
            if(authService.isAuthed()){
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }`

Comment: yes...assuming that `isAuthed()` is synchronous and isn't making a `$http` request. Also should return something from resolve

Comment: Hhmm - so i tested using a basic function `self.isAuthed = function() {
    return false;
  }` and i got the error `Unknown provider: authServiceProvider <- authService <- check`

Comment: Did you add "authService" in your app dependencies ? For example: angular.module('yourApp', ['authService']);

Comment: Yep `angular.module('theRoutes', ['ngRoute', 'authService'])` It now complains that the service is not available. Its def ok as I use it in other controllers

Comment: Got it - had a spelling mistake but everything you said was right.